# Efficiently filter data into multiple variables in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How would I do following more efficiently without iterating twice through the zipped list:

```py
x = [(item1['a'], item2) for item1, item2 in zip(foo, bar)]
y = [item2.replace(item1['b'], '') for item1, item2 in zip(foo, bar)]
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, just don't use list comprehension. Initialize x and y, then do the for loop with the zip. Inside of the one and only for loop, append to both x and y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly less Pythonic:

```
x = []
y = []
for item1,item2 in zip(foo,bar):
    x.append((item1['a'],item2))
    y.append(item2.replace(item1['b'],''))
```

Comment: why is that less pythonic? :)

Comment: @Tomerikoo: it is just my opinion ;)

Comment: I just think people tend to get fixated on list-comps and sometimes (like this case) a good old-fashioned loop is more pythonic (simple is better than complex and all that...)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use a generator expression to output multiple values as tuples and then `zip` the outputting sequence of tuples into individual sequences so that you can unpack them into separate variables.

So instead of, for example:

```
x = [i + 1 for i in lst]
y = [i + 2 for i in lst]
```

You can do:

```
x, y = zip(*((i + 1, i + 2) for i in lst))
```

In this case `x` and `y` will become tuples, however, so if you need `x` and `y` to be actual lists instead you can `map` the outputting sequence to the `list` constructor:

```
x, y = map(list, zip(*((i + 1, i + 2) for i in lst)))
```

So the statements in your question can be rewritten as:

```
x, y = map(list, zip(*(((item1['a'], item2), item2.replace(item1['b'], '')) for item1, item2 in zip(foo, bar))))
```

Comment: These come out as tuples rather than lists.